# Rotate desktop 90/180 degrees in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, desktop

I Windows 7 and so can you rotate your desktop 90, 270 degrees. Is there any way to do this in Windows Server 2008 R2? I did find some software that works with 2003 servers...

Answer (score 1):

The [ASUS M2N-VM HDMI](http://techwiki.hardwarecanucks.com/product/1OTEyNzM5NjM5NTc4NjI/ASUS-M2N-VM-HDMI/#spec) should have an onboard NVidia Geforce 7 series. Try downloading and installing the [64bit Geforce drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7-winvista-64bit-258.96-whql-driver.html). Install them and you should get a system tray utility that will let you rotate the screen.

The link above says it's for Win7 and Vista only but Win2k8 R2 should be binary compatible with these operating systems. I've linked to the 64bit drivers since Win2k8 R2 is 64bit only.
 Let us know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the video card driver manufacturers provide user-configuration software which allow you to rotate. Failing a built-in Windows solution, contact your vendor's site for any driver configuration software.

Comment: Well, i only use the standard video card that is build in. Is a M2N-VM HDMI Moderboard.

Answer (score 0):

I've found ctrl-alt-arrow keys will do the trick on XP and 2003 - not sure about 2008.
That said, I've seen it mentioned that this only works with Intel graphics chipsets.

Comment: This do not work.. allready tested

Comment: These shortcuts are a feature of the nVidia and ATI driver suites, not standard Windows functionality

Answer (score 0):

This is a function of the graphics driver and not the operating system.  you should be able to do this with either Intel, nVidia or ATi/AMD graphics, once you install the relevant software.